# Can any body explain the logic mentioned in the description?

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic

The best way to get the month name when you have the month number is

Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , @MonthNumber , 0 ) - 1 )

Comment: You can find it from [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) and [DateName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

the inner query

```
select  DateAdd( month , 12 , 0 )-1
```

will give output as

```
1900-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Sql server considers starting date as 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000  with that date it adds 12 months will get 1901-01-01 00:00:00.000

from this value when you subtract one day and take the monthname, you get december, which is your desired output